# Noether's theorem: Lagrangian symmetry test

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, noethers-theorem

I have to perform a symmetry test in an exercise given an Lagrangian
$L(q, \dot{q}, t)$ invariant under
\begin{equation}
t' = t + \delta t \\
q' = q + \delta q.
\end{equation} I found the following **symmetry test** in my notes
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \delta q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q}\delta \dot q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\delta t + L \frac{d (\delta t)}{d t} = 0,
\end{equation}
but have quite some issues to derive the upper statement.

> Could somebody give me a hint on where to start?

Until now I tried
\begin{equation}
L' - L = 0
\end{equation}
with $L'(q+\delta q, \dot q + \delta \dot q, t+\delta t)$, but do not know how to get to the 4th term of the symmetry test $L \frac{d(\delta t)}{d t}$.

Comment: The Lagrangian is allowed to change by up to a total derivative; the difference needn't be zero, as we care if the action is invariant. I am voting to close as a homework question as this is essentially a 'derive this relation' question and nothing else.

Comment: This would be welcome on [this site](http://physics.qandaexchange.com/?qa=questions). Here, however, I don't think it is quite appropriate.

Comment: @heather The site you linked is clearly a bad copy of stackexchange. There have been 53 questions asked in total and I am pretty sure that the community mostly consists of the authors of the page like you.

Comment: @Knowledge, it is a site still in development that allows homework questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your criterion refers to the invariance of the *action*, not of the lagrangian. Invariance of the lagrangian is only interesting if $t'=t$ (or, more generally, if the jacobian of parameters transformations equals one, e.g. for a Lorentz transformation of the coordinates $x^\mu$).

The equation of motions will be invariant under the transformation $(t,q)\to (t',q')$ if the action: $$S[q',t'_1,t'_2]=S[q,t_1,t_2].$$
Note that this is a *sufficient* condition (the action may be invariant modulo a boundary term). Now, by a change of variables: $$S[q',t'_1,t'_2]=\intop _{t_1'}^{t_2'} L(q',\frac{\text d q'}{\text d t'},t')\text d t'=\intop _{t_1}^{t_2} L(q',\frac{\text d q'}{\text d t'},t')\frac{\text d t'}{\text d t}\text d t.$$
Here I'm assuming that $t'=t'(t)$ doesn't depend on the coordinates. This is equal to $S[q,t_1,t_2]$ for all choices of the interval $[t_1,t_2]$ if and only if $$L(q',\frac{\text d q'}{\text d t'},t')\frac{\text d t'}{\text d t}=L(q,\frac{\text d q}{\text d t},t).$$ In particular, the lagrangian is *not* invariant (it gets multiplied by the jacobian factor of $t\leftrightarrow t'$). Now substitute the infinitesimal form of $t'-t$, $q'-q$, keep only first order terms, and you obtain the desired result.